# How to pass Google reCAPTCHA v2 response code to server side PHP page using AJAX-jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

Form is not submitting using AJAX-jQuery and thus not getting response key on server side PHP page.

**Form Page**

This part is quite straight forward and looking like below.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<form name="frm_add" id="frm_add" novalidate>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls input-group"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div> 

    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY-SITE-KEY"></div>
    <div id="success"></div>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

**JQuery / AJAX Page**

If I remove `g-recaptcha-response: grecaptcha.getResponse(),` code from this JS page then page submits without any issue using jQuery-AJAX and everything goes well. But when I put above piece of code as written in below sample code then form doesn't submit using POST method so I guess something is wrong with this piece of code. I searched and read many tutorials and codes on internet but could not able to resolve this issue.

```
$(function() {
    $("#frm_add input,#frm_add textarea ,#frm_add select").jqBootstrapValidation( {
        .
        .
        $.ajax({
            url: "./user/offer_p.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                g-recaptcha-response: grecaptcha.getResponse(),
                name: name
            },
            cache: false,
        .
        .
    }
}
```

**Server Side PHP Page**

If I submit form directly using POST method (without jQuery-AJAX POST method) then below code works properly.

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$secretkey = "MY-SECRET-KEY";
$responsekey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

$post_data = http_build_query(
    array (
        'secret' => $secretkey,
        'response' => $responsekey,
        'remoteip' => $ipaddress
    )
);  

$options=array (
    'http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $post_data
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);   
$result_json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$resulting = json_decode($result_json, true);

if($resulting["success"] != 1)
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalide Captcha!";
    echo json_encode($response); 
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side PHP Page**

```
  $response = file_get_contents ( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY . "&response=" . $_POST ['g-recaptcha-response'] . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
  $responseData = json_decode ( $response );

  if ($responseData->success) {
                 // TRUE
  }else{
               //False
  }
```

Comment: Ty for response but 'g-recaptcha-response: grecaptcha.getResponse(),' this piece of code in JS file is not working properly and thus value is not passing from HTML form to server side PHP page. Please suggest about this issue.

Comment: I tried your method too but still not receiving response value in POST variable.